# Where the execution starts in VB

Tags: vb6

i want to know where the execution starts from, in VB. for ex: In oops languages execution start from the main(), according to VB i don't know where the execution starts?

Comment: VB.NET or VB6?  The answer is different depending on which language you are talking about.

Comment: Yes, please remove either the Vb.Net or that Vb6 tag, they're different languages and the answer is different for each.

Comment: Actually WinMain() gets called for a GUI program. The optional Main() in VB6 and the Main() in VFred or C# aren't the "real" Main or WinMain either. That lives in the runtime just as it does in Java.  "Oops" languages huh?  Great term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It also begins in `Main`.

See [Main Procedure in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235406.aspx) on MSDN:

> Every Visual Basic application must contain a procedure called Main. This procedure serves as the starting point and overall control for your application.

Comment: The question is tagged as Vb6, this doesn't necessarily apply.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - The question is also tagged VB.NET. Unless the OP clarifies, we will never know. Regardless, VB6 also has a `Main` function that is the entry point.

Comment: A thousand apologies, I didn't see the Vb.Net tag, however Vb6 apps don't necessarily have to have a main method, the project can nominate a form as the startup object.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - To be honest, it's been a long time since I've done any work on VB6.

Comment: Can't you just push F8 in VB.net and it takes you through the process step by step, from the very absolute beginning?

Answer (score 3):

vb also has a main routine.  However, it tends to be hidden / auto generated when working in Visual Studio.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235406(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Where is the main function in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258909/where-is-the-main-function-in-vb-net)